# Adding Priority to a TFS WorkItem

Tags: vb.net

I am writing code in VB to programmatically enter new WorkItems in TFS. I am able to set most of the fields correctly, but I cannot figure out how to set the Priority.

I set fields in the following manner:

```
        WorkItem task = project.WorkItemTypes["TASK"].NewWorkItem();
        task.Title = "Test Task";
        task.Description = "This is a task that must be tested.";
        task.Fields["Original Estimate"].Value = 10;
        task.Fields["Remaining Work"].Value = 6;
        task.Fields["Completed Work"].Value = 4;
        task.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = "Test User";
```

If anyone has any information on how to set the Priority, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Is there a problem with `task.Fields["Priority"].Value`, does it crash, not set, something else?

Comment: @DaveShaw: You are correct. That was pretty stupid on my part. I searched through the documentation and lists of what could be used in the Fields property, but never found Priority in that list. It was stupid of me not to try it anyway. Thank you.

Comment: Added it as an answer, with a bit more thought :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it using the name or refName:

- `task.Fields["Priority"].Value`
- `task.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"].Value`

on the `WorkItem`.

The reason it is not available as a property, is that only items with a refName in `System` appear on the WorkItem class. I guess this give MS freedom to change / remove anything not in `System` from Work Items / Templates that do not need it.